# Function wrapper for another functions

Tags: javascript

I have found that a lot of my API calls functions change `loading` property to `true` in the beginning and to `false` after it's finished. The thing is I have a lot of functions and I like to keep my code DRY.

So, I came up with something like this:

```
async loadingWrap (func, ...args) {
  this.loading = true

  await func(...args)

  this.loading = false
}
```

and when I call it is like this:

```
await this.loadingWrap(
  this.someAsyncFunction, { param: 'Value' }
)
```

where what ideally I want would be:

```
await this.loadingWrap(this.someAsyncFunction({ param: 'Value'}))
```

so it will look like a normal function to the future reader (me or someone else).

Is that possible? I looked at higher-order functions, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can almost get what you want. What you need to do is to not pass the arguments and call the function without any arguments. This behaves similarly to native functions that accept callbacks like `setTimeout()` or `addEventListener()`:

```
async loadingWrap (func) {
  this.loading = true

  await func()

  this.loading = false
}
```

Then call it similar to how you'd call functions like `setTimeout()`:

```
await this.loadingWrap(() => this.someAsyncFunction({ param: 'Value'}))
```

The trick is to wrap your function in an anonymous function that accepts no arguments - just like other functions like it in the js world.

Here's a full working demo with `console.log` replacing the `loading` variable:

```js
async function loadingWrap (func) {
  console.log('loading');
  
  await func()
    
  console.log('done loading');
}

function timer (x) {
  return new Promise((ok,fail) => setTimeout(ok,x));
}

async function test () {
  console.log('calling async function');

  await loadingWrap(() => timer(2000));

  console.log('finished calling async function');
}

test();
```

Comment: You're missing a couple pieces. 1. The arrow function needs to be defined as `async`, and 2. the call to `this.someAsyncFunction` needs to be called with `await`. Otherwise the `await` in `loadingWrap` won't work because it calls the arrow function, and the async part of `this.someAsyncFunction` won't work because the code wasn't told to `await`.

Comment: It might also be useful to show that the arrow function is just a function wrapper. I would add another code block showing the equivalent call with the arrow function defined as a standard function, just for clarity.

Comment: Remember what happens when you call an async function without await? That's right, it returns a promise. And what exactly do we do with the return value of the regular (not marked with `async`) arrow function? That's right, we await it internally. So we are awaiting a promise returned by the arrow function. This all works without adding async to the arrow function or await to the wrapped function. Try it

Comment: You're right, my brain had for some reason wrapped the right side of your arrow function in braces. Your arrow function returns the Promise returned by `someAsyncFunction`, so everything works out. Also, thanks for adding a snippet. I love being able to run these things live. :)

Comment: I think it's the cleanest solution that one can come up with. Thanks - this a nice, concise code that does exactly what I wanted and is still very readable.

Answer (score 1):

From what you want:

```js
await this.loadingWrap(this.someAsyncFunction({ param: 'Value'}))
```

This won't work because it will treat the parameter as a nested function.
The order of operations will be:

1. Call `this.someAsyncFunction({ param: 'Value'})`
2. Call `this.loadingWrap(x)` where `x` is the return value of step 1

This type of function evaluation is exactly like mathematical functions, where to evaluate `f(g(x))` (*f* of *g*, given `x`), you first evaluate *g* given the value `x`, and then use the result to evaluate *f*.

## A possible solution...

You might be able to use JavaScript's [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object. As the docs say, you can use them on a function by using the `apply` trap.

You'll write your handler generically to handle any function trying to use a loading flag.

```js
const handler = {
  apply: async function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    thisArg.loading = true
    await target.apply(thisArg, argumentsList)
    thisArg.loading = false
  }
}
```

You will then create your `someAsyncFunction` member function by creating the proxy like this:

```js
YourClass.prototype.someAsyncFunction = new Proxy(someAsyncFunction, handler);
```

Then you call it like this:

```js
// inside some other async member function...
  await this.someAsyncFunction({ param: 'Value'})
```

Here is a run-able example (there's nothing on the page, just console output):

```js
class MyObj {
  constructor() {
    this.loading = false
  }

  async someAsyncFunction(val) {
    console.log(`entering someAsyncFunction: loading = ${this.loading}`)
    console.log(`calling this.asyncLoad...`)
    await this.asyncLoad({
      value: val
    })
    console.log(`exiting someAsyncFunction: loading = ${this.loading}`)
  }
}

async function asyncLoad(params) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(`entering asyncLoad: loading = ${this.loading}, value = ${params.value}`)
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`exiting asyncLoad: loading = ${this.loading}, value = ${params.value}`)
      resolve()
    }, 1000)
  })
}

const handler = {
  apply: async function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    console.log('PROXY: setting load to true...')
    thisArg.loading = true
    console.log('PROXY: calling the proxied function...')
    await target.apply(thisArg, argumentsList)
    console.log('PROXY: setting load to false...')
    thisArg.loading = false
  }
}

MyObj.prototype.asyncLoad = new Proxy(asyncLoad, handler);

async function run() {
  let myobj = new MyObj()
  console.log(`in run, before calling someAsyncFunction, loading = ${myobj.loading}`)
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`INTERRUPT: checking loading is true (${myobj.loading})`)
  }, 500)
  await myobj.someAsyncFunction(1)
  console.log(`in run, after calling someAsyncFunction, loading = ${myobj.loading}`)
}
run()
```

### Selective Proxy-ing

If the function you're trying to call is generic enough that you only need to perform Proxy actions *sometimes*, this is entirely do-able. This is also where `Proxy` becomes really cool, because you can create *different* proxies to perform different actions while maintaining the same base code.

In the example below, `asyncLoad` is my generic function, and I can `call` it providing an instance of `ObjWithoutStatus` as the function's `this` context. But I also created two proxies, one to set the `loading` status, and another to set the `loaderIsRunning` status. Each of these end up calling the base function, without having to perform the gymnastics of creating wrappers that maintain the correct scope.

```js
class ObjWithoutStatus {
  constructor() {}
}

class ObjWithLoading {
  constructor() {
    this.loading = false
  }
}

class ObjWithLoaderIsRunning {
  constructor() {
    this.loaderIsRunning = false
  }
}

async function asyncLoad(params) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    console.log(`entering asyncLoad: loading = ${this.loading}, value = ${params.value}`)
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`exiting asyncLoad: loading = ${this.loading}, value = ${params.value}`)
      resolve()
    }, 1000)
  })
}

const handler_loading = {
  apply: async function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    console.log('PROXY_loading: setting load to true...')
    thisArg.loading = true
    console.log('PROXY_loading: calling the proxied function...')
    await target.apply(thisArg, argumentsList)
    console.log('PROXY_loading: setting load to false...')
    thisArg.loading = false
  }
}

const handler_loaderIsRunning = {
  apply: async function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    console.log('PROXY_loaderIsRunning: setting load to true...')
    thisArg.loaderIsRunning = true
    console.log('PROXY_loaderIsRunning: calling the proxied function...')
    await target.apply(thisArg, argumentsList)
    console.log('PROXY_loaderIsRunning: setting load to false...')
    thisArg.loaderIsRunning = false
  }
}

const asyncLoad_loading = new Proxy(asyncLoad, handler_loading)
const asyncLoad_loaderIsRunning = new Proxy(asyncLoad, handler_loaderIsRunning)

const x = new ObjWithoutStatus()
const y = new ObjWithLoading()
const z = new ObjWithLoaderIsRunning()

async function run() {

  console.log(`in run, before calling asyncLoad, x.loading, x.loaderIsRunning = ${x.loading}, ${x.loaderIsRunning}`)
  setTimeout(() => console.log(`INTERRUPT_asyncLoad: x.loading, x.loaderIsRunning = ${x.loading}, ${x.loaderIsRunning}`), 500)
  await asyncLoad.call(x, {
    value: 1
  })
  console.log(`in run, after calling asyncLoad, x.loading, x.loaderIsRunning = ${x.loading}, ${x.loaderIsRunning}`)

  console.log(`in run, before calling asyncLoad_loading, y.loading = ${y.loading}`)
  setTimeout(() => console.log(`INTERRUPT_asyncLoad_loading: y.loading = ${y.loading}`), 500)
  await asyncLoad_loading.call(y, {
    value: 2
  })
  console.log(`in run, after calling asyncLoad_loading, y.loading = ${y.loading}`)

  console.log(`in run, before calling asyncLoad_loaderIsRunning, z.loaderIsRunning = ${z.loaderIsRunning}`)
  setTimeout(() => console.log(`INTERRUPT_asyncLoad_loading: z.loaderIsRunning = ${z.loaderIsRunning}`), 500)
  await asyncLoad_loaderIsRunning.call(z, {
    value: 3
  })
  console.log(`in run, after calling asyncLoad_loaderIsRunning, z.loaderIsRunning = ${z.loaderIsRunning}`)

}
run()
```

Comment: That's true! I so wanted to make it work that I forgot about this evn though I knew (and used) it before. Thanks for a reminder!

Comment: @jeand'arme I've added a possible solution for you. Pay specific attention to how `MyObj.prototype.asyncLoad` is defined, and how `MyObj.someAsyncFunction` is called. While the code is a little daunting, once you wrap your head around it, you'll see that it makes the handler generic, and you can use that same handler with any class function that needs to set/unset loading as part of its asynchronous operation.

Comment: I was looking at Proxies yesterday, but couldn't apply them here so nice work! My question is it generic enough to use it with most function, but not all of them? I have a lot of functions that I call once, maybe twice - and here I see it's about defining prototypes. Also, I'm trying to keep readability, but can't deny that Proxy looks interesting.

Comment: @jeand'arme Are you suggesting that you want to call `someAsyncFunction` sometimes with and sometimes without setting the `this.loading` flag? This is exactly what Proxy is built for. I'll add a small code block to expand on this.

Comment: @jeand'arme I've added a larger-than-expected snippet that does a couple things. It avoids making the function part of the object prototypes so you can use `call` to provide the `this` context you want generically, and it shows how you can basically extend a generic function by using proxies, and then calling them in the exact same way you call your original function.

Comment: All this looks very interesting and I actually like Proxies, but man it's way more complicated compared to @slebetman's answer. I put readability above many things so I'll probably stick to his answer, but I really appreciate the effort you put into it.

Comment: There's really no good reason to use a proxy here.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you need to make sure the `this` value is correctly set when the actual function is called:

```
async loadingWrap (func, thisArg, ...args) {
  this.loading = true;
  // support functions that resolve to something useful. And provide `this`
  let result = await func.apply(thisArg, args);
  this.loading = false
  return result; 
}
```

And in some `async` method:

```
  let result = await this.loadingWrap(
    this.someAsyncFunction, this, { param: 'Value' }
  );
  console.log(result);
```

If you don't like the extra parameter, then you must pass a callback function that sets the `this` binding correctly, and then you might as well settle the arguments at the same time:

```
async loadingWrap (func) {
  this.loading = true;
  let result = await func();
  this.loading = false
  return result; 
}
```

And in some `async` method, note the callback function:

```
  let result = await this.loadingWrap(
    () => this.someAsyncFunction({ param: 'Value' })
  );
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a higher order function, which is just a function that returns a function. Lodash uses techniques like this for functions like `throttle` or `debounce`.

```
// Wrap your function in another function that sets the loading property.
// We're passing "this" as "that" to preserve it when loadStuff is called.
function loadingWrap(that, functionToWrap) {
    return async function() {
        that.loading = true;
        let returnVal = await functionToWrap.apply(that, arguments);
        that.loading = false;
        return returnVal;
    }
}

// In your API class
public loadStuff1 = loadingWrap(this, (arg1, arg2) => {
    // This method must return a promise for the loading wrap to work.
    return http.get('someURL', arg1, arg2);
});

// In the class that uses your api
myAPI.loadStuff1('abc', 123);
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider using wrapper like this:

```js
function bar(fn) {
  console.log('before');
  fn();
  console.log('after');
}

function baz(...params) {
  console.log('inside', params);
}

bar(() => baz(1, 2, 3));
```

```
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.loading = false;
  }

  async loadable(fn) {
      this.loading = true;
      await fn();
      this.loading = false;
  }

  async load() {
    return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 2000))
  }

  async fetch() {
    this.loadable(this.load); // or () => this.load(params)
  }
}

new A().fetch();
```